# Keep value if not in case_when statement

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
df <- expand.grid(grade = c("A", 1, "B", 2, 3, "C"), value = c(0, 1))
```

When I try to replace the `A`, `B`, and `C`s in a `case_when` statement, the non-replaced values go to `NA`... I want them to stay!

Attempt:

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- df %>% 
mutate(grade = case_when(
.$grade == "A" ~ 1,
.$grade == "B" ~ 2,
.$grade == "C" ~ 3))
```

Desired output:

```
df <- data.frame(grade = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4)), value = rep(c(0, 1), 6))
```

Note** Looking for `case_when` solution NOT `ifelse` solution.

Comment: If you used stringsAsFactors=FALSE in the expand.grid construction of df then the answer by TJMahr would probably succeed. (And yours would ahve succeeded except for all the NA's for the non-included case values.)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`case_when` statements are two-sided formulas where the left-hand side is a logical test and the right-hand side is the value to assign when that test is `TRUE`.

Values that are never matched by a logical test get a default replacement value: `NA`. To keep these values from getting `NA`s, include a final catch-all test and replacement.

```r
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(old_grade = grade) |>
  select(old_grade, grade, value) |>
  mutate(grade = case_when(
    grade == "A" ~ 1,
    grade == "B" ~ 2,
    grade == "C" ~ 3,
    TRUE ~ as.numeric(as.character(grade)))
  )
#> Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
#> ℹ In argument: `grade = case_when(...)`.
#> Caused by warning:
#> ! NAs introduced by coercion
#>    old_grade grade value
#> 1          A     1     0
#> 2          1     1     0
#> 3          B     2     0
#> 4          2     2     0
#> 5          3     3     0
#> 6          C     3     0
#> 7          A     1     1
#> 8          1     1     1
#> 9          B     2     1
#> 10         2     2     1
#> 11         3     3     1
#> 12         C     3     1
```

Update (2023): `case_when()` now includes a `.default` argument:

```r
df |>
  mutate(old_grade = grade) |>
  select(old_grade, grade, value) |>
  mutate(grade = case_when(
    grade == "A" ~ 1,
    grade == "B" ~ 2,
    grade == "C" ~ 3,
    .default = as.numeric(as.character(grade)))
  )
#> Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
#> ℹ In argument: `grade = case_when(...)`.
#> Caused by warning in `vec_case_when()`:
#> ! NAs introduced by coercion
#>    old_grade grade value
#> 1          A     1     0
#> 2          1     1     0
#> 3          B     2     0
#> 4          2     2     0
#> 5          3     3     0
#> 6          C     3     0
#> 7          A     1     1
#> 8          1     1     1
#> 9          B     2     1
#> 10         2     2     1
#> 11         3     3     1
#> 12         C     3     1
```

More update (2023): A function with a similar purpose, `case_match()`, has also been added to dplyr:

```r
df |>
  mutate(old_grade = grade) |>
  select(old_grade, grade, value) |>
  mutate(
    grade = case_match(
      grade,
      "A" ~ "1",
      "B" ~ "2",
      "C" ~ "3",
      .default = as.character(grade),
    ),
    # do conversion here to avoid warnings
    grade = as.numeric(grade)
  )
#>    old_grade grade value
#> 1          A     1     0
#> 2          1     1     0
#> 3          B     2     0
#> 4          2     2     0
#> 5          3     3     0
#> 6          C     3     0
#> 7          A     1     1
#> 8          1     1     1
#> 9          B     2     1
#> 10         2     2     1
#> 11         3     3     1
#> 12         C     3     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.2)</sup>

Comment: I think you need `as.numeric(as.character(.$grade))` or else you got the numeric factor levels instead of the actual value.

Comment: @aosmith I never use factors because of things like this, so I'm not surprised this tripped me up here.

Comment: Note the `.$` notation can be removed and the solution works fine.

Answer (score -2):

After struggling with this as well and still getting this error with @TJ Mahr's answer. Found out the problem was that is still had NAs. I just made a new line with an ifelse vector. In this example:

```
old_grade <- df %>%
  mutate(grade = case_when(
  #conditions here
  )

ifelse(is.na(grade), grade, old_grade))
```

Comment: Your `case_when` is not wrapped in a `mutate` statement.  Your assignment creates a new vector rather than modifying a column in the original data frame.

Comment: @Limey you're right, I forgot to put it in the code here. But I ran it in my case with mutate I just accidentally removed it when changing to this case. Added the mutate in an edit now

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33235335)