# dynamic variables in mutate/case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to conditionally replace values in a df using mutate, case_when, and dynamic variables.

Specifically, for each of a set of variables, I want to replace that variable's values with NA when some condition is met, and leave the values untouched otherwise.

Example:

```
data("iris")
df=iris

dynamicVars=c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width")

#this runs but changes every observation to NA (the default)
for (var in dynamicVars){
  df=mutate(df,"{var}" := case_when(Species == "setosa" ~ NA))
}

#this is what I want conceptually (but doesn't run) 
for (var in dynamicVars){
  df=mutate(df,"{var}" := case_when(Species == "setosa" ~ NA, 
                                    TRUE ~ {var})) #this bit generates error
}
```

The `"{var}":=` bit seems to be working ok to assign values to a dynamic variable.

But how do I instruct `case_when` to use the old value? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257820/keep-value-if-not-in-case-when-statement) explains how to use the `TRUE` condition (essentially an "else" if I understand correctly) to refer back to the original variable, but not sure how to make that work for the dynamic case. Hoping there's some other way to access the contents of `var` in the specific context of `case_when/TRUE`?

[Bonus for removing the for loop]

Comment: `{var}` doesn’t do anything special. To trigger tidy evaluation you’d have to use `{{var}}`, but that would evaluate to a string. You’d need `!! as.name(var)`. But this *still* doesn’t work because the `case_when()` expression is invalid: `case_when(df$Species == "setosa" ~ NA, TRUE ~ 1)` also results in an error, but it works with a non-`NA` value. — That said, use the method from r2evans’ answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `across` for this:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(any_of(dynamicVars), ~ case_when(Species == "setosa" ~ NA, TRUE ~ .))) %>%
  slice_head(n = 3, by = Species)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 1           NA          NA          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 2           NA          NA          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 3           NA          NA          1.3         0.2     setosa
# 4          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 5          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# 6          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
# 7          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
# 8          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
# 9          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
```

(The `slice_head` was merely to show a few rows of each `Species`.)

The choice of `any_of` was somewhat arbitrary, there's also `all_of(.)` (as seen in @user438383's answer).

I'm assuming that you have further needs for `case_when`, if not then `if_else` works just fine.

Comment: that was fast, thx. but using your exact code I get an error: <error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `Sepal.Length`.

Comment: solved: outdated dplyr package was the culprit. works beautifully now

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` with `replace`.

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(df)[, (vars) := lapply(.SD, \(x) replace(x, Species == "setosa", NA)), 
+           .SDcols={vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")}]
> df
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:           NA          NA          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:           NA          NA          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:           NA          NA          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:           NA          NA          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:           NA          NA          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                            
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- iris
```

Comment: I like the use of `(vars) := ..., .SDcols={vars <- ...}`, I am hoping the dev team will eventually be able to implement something like `names(.SD) := ...` (one of the many suggestions for this case).